# Serialize CGAffineTransform to store in NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios

How would I store a CGAffineTransform in NSUserDefaults?
Since it contains 6 float values it takes a lot of repetitive work to store each value as float... so I'm wondering if there is a smarter way.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use NSStringFromCGAffineTransform() and CGAffineTransformFromString().

Using NSValue, I got:

> -[NSUserDefaults setObject:forKey:]: Attempt to insert non-property value 'CGAffineTransform: {{0.9291659, 0, 0, -0.9291659}, {41.675232, 823.75122}}' of class 'NSConcreteValue'.  Note that dictionaries and arrays in property lists must also contain only property values.

Comment: Hmm right dunno why I checked the other since NSValue doesn't really go into the user defaults...

Answer (score 8):

Wrap it in an `NSValue` instance:

```
NSValue *affineTransformValue = [NSValue valueWithCGAffineTransform:myTransform];
```