# Saving Transforms into NSUserDefaults?

Tags: iphone, nsuserdefaults, save

I am making a game, and want to save the states of the game scene.
I know we can save CGPoints into NSUSerDefaults, but is there any way to
save "Transform" into it?

If not, is there any function to "read" a transform (for eg, the scale/angle of a view)?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Serialize CGAffineTransform to store in NSUserDefaults](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4469731/serialize-cgaffinetransform-to-store-in-nsuserdefaults)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple, wrap it in an `NSValue`:

```
CGAffineTransform t;

[userDefaults setObject:[NSValue valueWithCGAffineTransform:t] forKey:@"Transform"];
```